# how to set up an background image on the panel in java such that my buttons are clearly visible?

Tags: java

here my buttons on panel are visible only when i place my mouse over them and secret password button and JTextfield even then not visible .please suggest some ideas to get over this problem.I have three buttons and labels and text field.

```
public class FileOperation extends JFrame
{
    private Player player;
    private File file;
    private class BackgroundPanel extends Panel  
    {  
    Image img;  
    public BackgroundPanel()  
    {  
    try  
    {  
    img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("17.jpg");  
    }  
    catch(Exception e){/*handled in paint()*/}  
    }  
@Override 
public void paint(Graphics g)  
{  
super.paint(g);  
if(img != null) g.drawImage(img, 0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this); 
else g.drawString("No Image",100,100);  
}

}
 public FileOperation()
 {
     super( "File Protection Tool" );
     BackgroundPanel panel = new BackgroundPanel();
     panel.setLayout (null);
     JLabel label5=new JLabel("SecretPassword");    
     final JTextField hashkey = new JTextField(15);
     JButton openFilee = new JButton( "Open file to encrypt" );
     openFilee.addActionListener( new ActionListener() 
     {
         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
         {
             openFile(0,hashkey);
         }
     });
    JButton openFiled = new JButton("Open file to decrypt");
    openFiled.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent d )
        {
            openFile(1,hashkey);
        }
    });
    JButton openFilefol = new JButton("Choose folder to lock");
    openFilefol.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent d )
        {
            openFilefol();
        }
    });
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
setSize(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2);
setLocation(screenWidth / 4, screenHeight / 4);
setTitle("FileEncrypt");
hashkey.setBounds(200,210,150,20);
    label5.setBounds(100,210,150,20);
openFilee.setBounds(50,120,190,20);
openFiled.setBounds(300,120,190,20);
openFilefol.setBounds(80,240,190,20);
panel.add(openFilee);
panel.add(openFiled);
panel.add(openFilefol);
panel.add(label5);
panel.add(hashkey);
panel.setVisible(true);
getContentPane().add(panel);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JPanel instead of Panel and override paintComponent

```
private class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel  
    {  
    Image img;  
    public BackgroundPanel()  
    {  
    try  
    {  
    img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("17.jpg");  
    }  
    catch(Exception e){/*handled in paint()*/}  
    }  
@Override 
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
{  
super.paintComponent(g);  
if(img != null) g.drawImage(img, 0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this); 
else g.drawString("No Image",100,100);  
}

}
```